# Prove that $a^{2b}+b^{2a}\leq 1$ if $a,b>0$ such that $a+b=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: inequality, exponentiation

> > let $a,b>0$ such that $a+b=\frac{1}{2}$ then we have :
> >     $$a^{2b}+b^{2a}\leq 1$$

### My try :

I have tried to apply Bernoulli's inequality :

$$f(a)=a^{2(\frac{1}{2}-a)}=(1+a-1)^{2(\frac{1}{2}-a)}\leq g(a)=1+(a-1)(2)(\frac{1}{2}-a)$$

On the other hand we have :
$$f(\frac{1}{2}-a)\leq g(\frac{1}{2}-a)$$

Unfortunately we have :

$$g(\frac{1}{2}-a)+g(a)\geq 1$$

So I was wondering myself if we have some good bound using power series but I found nothing really interesting and usefull .

The equality case are $a=b=0.25$ or $a=0$ and $b=0.5$

Any helps is greatly appreciated .

Thanks in advance for all your contributions .

### Update

> > Let $a\geq b>0$ such that $a+b=0.5$ then the function :
> >     $$(ax+b(1-x))^{2(a(1-x)+b(x))}=f(x)$$
> >     Is $3$-concave or $f'''(x)\leq 0$ on $(0,1)$

So we can apply the [Levinson's inequality](https://journalofinequalitiesandapplications.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13660-019-2166-8) the theorem B . It gives inequality like :

$$\frac{f(0)}{2}-f(0.125)\geq \frac{f(0.5)}{2}-f(0.375)$$

Maybe it's usefull.

Comment: @RiverLi Have you an advice to me ?

Comment: Just a hint.  Define $f(x)=x^{1-2x}+(0.5-x)^{2x}$.  That function is symmetric around $x=0.5$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe around $x=0.25$ no?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that typo.  From here there must be an extreme value of $f$ in $x=1/4$ and, of course, in $x=0$ and $x=1/2$.

Comment: @The.old.boy  Use appropriate bounds, just like e.g. Proposition 5.2 in  Vasile Cirtoaje, "Proofs of three open inequalities with power-exponential functions", The Journal of Nonlinear Sciences and its Applications (2011), Volume: 4, Issue: 2, page 130-137. https://eudml.org/doc/223938